# Fixed-width formatting in Dart

Tags: dart

I am writing a script to generate a file with the structure of a molecule represented in MDL's `**.mol**' format.  It requires writing several pieces of data with exactly specified widths (*i.e.*, 2 characters and space-padded on the right, 3 characters and space-padded on the left, *etc.*).  How do I do this in Dart?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible using string interpolation. There is a bug here:

http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=1694

You should star it to express your support in having this fixed.

In the meantime, you could manually construct a string character by character that fits your needs.

John